# Existence of basis of solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

Show that the function $\cos(2x) -2\cos^2(x)$ and $\cos(2x)- 2 \sin^2(x)$ cannot be a basis of solution of any Differential Equation with second order.